# Apache rewrite - get original URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite in nginx or Apache for this address:

```
http://domain.com/hello
```

to a script like

```
http://domain.com/test.php&ref=hell
```

How can I access this rewritten URL in PHP? Because, if I use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` of course I get:

```
/test.php&ref=hell
```

but I only want:

```
/hello
```

Is this possible? Thanx for help.

**Upd nginx cnf**

```
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

server
{
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.test;


  location /
  {
    rewrite ^/(main|best|air)$ /core/feeds.php?act=$1 last;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your rewrite code? In apache, REQUEST_URI should return the URI the user used to get to the page. This is the behaviour i get when using modrewrite. I can't help but think your doing a redirect instead of a modrewrite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Nginx` conf, we need to add user header with `request_uri`:

```
proxy_set_header request_uri $request_uri;
```

And read it in `php`:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REQUEST_URI'];
```

**upd**

for some reason nginx don't like symbol '_' in header name, don't know how it worked before, maybe something changed after nginx update. Now i'm using

```
proxy_set_header rewriteduri $request_uri;
```

and in php

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REWRITEDURI']
```

Comment: it should be noted that some apache configurations prepend 'HTTP_' to env vars like this, so it may be at `$_SERVER['request_uri']` (note case as well)

Comment: for some reason nginx don't like symbol '_' in header name, don't know how it worked before, maybe something changed after nginx update. Now i'm using

---
I think you are missing the "underscores_in_headers on;" directive on /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file

Answer (score 12):

It really depends on the PHP setup. With mod_php you oftentimes still have the original request path in `REQUEST_URI`. For CGI or FastCGI setups it is quite commonly `REDIRECT_URL`. You will have to check a `phpinfo()` page to be sure.

If you really can't find anything that would help, then it's time for cheating! You can adapt your RewriteRule like this to retain the original URL in an environment variable of your chosing:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$   test.php?ref=$1    [E=ORIG_URI:/$1]
```

This would then be available as `$_SERVER["ORIG_URI"]`, or you can just get it from the URI with $_GET['ref'].
But you would have to use this trick on all potential RewriteRules.

Answer (score 6):

You can usually find the requested URL in

- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`
- `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` (maybe Apache only, don't know about nginx)

I know you mentioned `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains your rewritten URL but in all my tests, it contains the original request.

Why don't you dump `$_SERVER` and see what's in there.

Comment: Not that it was asked but, for future reference in case searched for, `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL']` for IIS7+ using the IIS Rewrite module

Comment: tried to do print_r($_SERVER) but don`t see what i wanna get, maybe it`s impossible without parsing and others…

Comment: And in case of search for apache2 :
`$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']`