# PHP url after mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, curl

Is there a way to get the actual url of a file after mod_rewrite using PHP or Curl?

### BASIC EXAMPLE

This --> example.com/test

I want this --> example.com/test.php

Comment: mod_rewrite will be converting your clean urls to actual urls, as you have given above.

Comment: Well yes, but I need some kind of function (or something) that can come back and tell me what is the actual url.

Comment: Which one are you trying to do? are you trying to find out if `example.com/test` is actually `example.com/test.php`?

Answer (score 7):

`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];` will give you original REQUEST_URI

`$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"];` will give you redirected URL.

Assuming you are just using `[L]` in your rewrite rule.

Comment: Looking for something externally, not the current page

Comment: By **externally** do you mean not in PHP? Do you want this value in .htaccess file?

Comment: sorry my mistake for that....  I mean, if I'm at test.com/index.php and I want it to find the actual url for example.com/test

Comment: Are you redirecting using `[R]` flag in .htaccess file?

Comment: Well I need it for sites (that I do not own) where I do not have access to .htaccess files.  Meaning I don't know how their htaccess files are set up

Comment: If `[R]` flag is not used then my answer posted above will work. If `[R]` (external redirection) has been used then it is little tricky. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493075/apache-rewrite-get-original-url-in-php

Comment: It would work on my domain, but I need it to check a document on another domain

Comment: Can you check with other domain admins what their rewrite rules are? As I said earlier If they are using `[R]` to redirect then it is an external redirect and the URL before redirect cannot be captured by above answer. Did you take a look at the other Stackoverlow answer I suggested above.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for that redirected version.

Answer (score 0):

Try $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] with caveats and some alternatives as well: http://www.mc2design.com/blog/php_self-safe-alternatives

Comment: Although this probably works, how would I go about a page other than the current one I am on.

Comment: New URL:  http://www.mc2design.com/blog/article/serverphp_self-can-not-be-trusted-but-there-are-safe-alternatives