# How to Make URLs case insensitive

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am facing a problem of duplicate links(according to Google Webmaster Tools)

for example google listed 4 kind of URLs as a duplicate to the actual URL

```
1) mysite.com/k-Summer Season-10.htm
2) mysite.com/k-Summer%20Season-10.htm
3) mysite.com/k-summer-season-10.htm (actual link)
4) mysite.com/K---10.htm
```

now if you take a look at the structure of 4th link, it clearly indecates that no matter what you write between /k- AND -10.htm 
you will get the content of page number 10, which can be anything like below.

```
1) mysite.com/k-Summer Season-10.htm
2) mysite.com/k-Bummer%20Season-10.htm
3) mysite.com/k-Dumber-season-10.htm
4) mysite.com/K-Mars-&-Earth-Season-10.htm
```

so is there a way to forbid opening rest of the URLs(case sensitive & with space) and give a 404 error OR redirect them to the actual link?

below are codes for my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^lightbox.htm$ lightbox.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^lightbox.([0-9]+).htm$ lightbox.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^search.htm$ search.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^search.([0-9]+).htm$ search.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^postcard([a-zA-Z0-9]+).htm$ postcards.php?postcard_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^postcard.img([0-9]+).htm$ postcards.php?image_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^k-(.*)-([0-9]+).htm categories.php?cat_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^cat.htm$ categories.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^r-(.*)-([0-9]+).htm details.php?image_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^r([0-9]+).search.htm details.php?image_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ google.php
```

kind regards

JoJAF

Comment: Not related to your question, but to add the original query-string you can use the `QSA` flag. So e.g. you second rule would be `RewriteRule ^lightbox.([0-9]+).htm$ lightbox.php?page=$1 [QSA]`

Answer (score 3):

Try specifying a `<link rel="canonical" />` tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://mysite.com/k-summer-season-10.htm" />
```

StackOverflow does this - have a look at the source for this page.  More information [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html).

---

Alternatively, in your PHP script, you can check the original URL against the real URL, and redirect users to the real URL if necessary.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493075/apache-rewrite-get-original-url-in-php) for details on how to get the original URL before any rewrite rules.

---

Finally, why are you using a `.htm` suffix in all of your URLs?  One of the benefits of a URL rewriting scheme is that you don't need things like that to clutter up your URLs.

Comment: Make sure you disable multiviews (`Options -MultiView`) if you choose you remove the `.html` part.

Comment: Thanks Garben for the suggestion, I have already started using <link rel="canonical" /> a month back after google panda slammed my site for duplicate conent, and about using ".htm" i am using 4images gallery on my site and it has a MOD "search engine friendly urls" which is responsible for all of these links result.