# Apache 2 mod_rewrite and PHP. Modify $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] value from htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^hello$ goodbye

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

So I'm receiving all the requests on `index.php`, but I get `hello` when asking for `hello`, and I expected to receive `goodbye` when printing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` from PHP.

That is, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` seems inmutable, even when the URL has been rewritten already before matching the RewriteRule referring `index.php`. Is there any way to modify this value?

I want to do this to add a thin and simple layer of URL preprocessing to some existing code, without modifying the PHP files. So I'm trying to stick inside the `.htaccess`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493075/apache-rewrite-get-original-url-in-php

Comment: Yes, the common approach is to set a new environment variable with [E=]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you made a mistake of not putting `L` or `PT` flag in your first rule. Your code should be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^hello$ goodbye [PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Once that code is there access this variable in `index.php`:

```
$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]
```

This will have value: **`/goodbye`**

#### EDIT

If you have `mod_proxy` enabled on your host, you can have your first rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^hello$ /goodbye [P]
```

And then you will have: **`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]=/goodbye`**