# Rewrite link url in browser

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, .htaccess

Something that is probably not possible. But...

I have a session stored (a name of a city) which I can echo from any point of my wordpress page, if the user has selected a city.

I was wondering if it was possible to echo this city to a custom url or something so that it looks like something like this www.mydomain.nl/city/things instead of www.mydomain.nl/things and not damage the link structure...

Probably not right?

Just to clarify - both pages show exactly the same content. I just want visitors to know what city they clicked. I got more then one. So www.domein.nl/city-x/things would show the same content as www.domein.nl/city-y/things

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? It's hard to understand what you need. Would `/city/things` serve different content than just `/things` ?

Comment: @apokryfos No, both url's would show exactly the same content. It's just that I have more cities on my site and I would like to have the user see where they are.. 

www.mydomain.nl/city-x/things shows the same content as www.mydomain.nl/city-y/things.

Comment: Try adding `RewriteRule ^(.*?)/things$ things [L]` in your `.htaccess` file (assuming mod_rewrite is enabled). This should serve /things on all requests which match /{something}/things.

Comment: Got it. But, how do I tell the {something} what he should be? And can {something} be dynamic content from a saved SESSION?

Comment: Sessions are typically loaded in the PHP side which happens after the `.htaccess` rules are evaluated (so I guess you can't do much about that). If you have a hardcoded list, you can do something like `RewriteRule ^(city1|city2|city3|city4...)/things$ things [NC, L]` but I see how this would be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: I think your best bet is to go for the first rule (which allows all) and then get the original request URL in PHP to determine if that's allowed. (Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493075/apache-rewrite-get-original-url-in-php for more details on this as I haven't tried it myself).

Comment: @apokryfos thanks. Im going to check it out. Sounds like a nightmare... But will read in to it.