# Is it possible to get the original URL after a 302 .htaccess RedirectMatch?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, redirect

Hello guys. I started coding my own "URL shortener". The basic idea is you use example.com/12345 to redirect to another URL. This "matching" is done by using .htaccess to redirect stuff towards a script that does (irrelevant for us now) stuff.

My .htaccess currently looks like this:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/\w{5}$ /redir.php
```

The redirect matches any string of exactly 5 and sends it toward my PHP script where the actual redirection to the expanded URL take place. The only problem is that I was unable to find a proper way of getting the original URL, the matched one into a variable.

As a sidenote the whole thing happens on a VPS set up by me with minimal knowledge, so if this problem *can* originate from a missing config ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] doesn't work), then expect my configs to not be 100% correct and by standards.

EDIT: changed from RedirectMatch to RewriteRule, still doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^\w{5}$ /redir.php [R,L]
```

Comment: Instead use something like base62 instead of an int and decode it into something workable like a database id. This lib will do it all. http://hashids.org/

Comment: Besides, the entropy in 10000 to 99999 is not much. And numbers are easy to traverse..

Comment: Oh and to answer the question, use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache rewrite - get original URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493075/apache-rewrite-get-original-url-in-php) (Terms entered into Google: _how to access original url in php after rewrite_)

Comment: Hey @CBroe, yes I did stumble upon that one while searching (before posting) but it didn't help, or i wasn't able to understand what's there well enough. In my case REQUEST_URI was empty, and aparently that is because I was using R=302 insetad of NC as a flag for RewriteRule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w{5})$ /redir.php?redir=$1 [R,L]
```

this will send the 5 letter string as querystring param `redir`. Which you can access in `redir.php` as:

```
$_GET['redir']
```

**Edit:** Or as @LawrenceCherone have suggested you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in redir.php. But for that you have to use `NC` flag in `.htaccess` instead, Like:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w{5})$ /redir.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Ok this seems to work. I'm currently not doing any redirects in my script so the page remains on /redir.php?redir=stuff and YES I can use that as a variable, I just hope that when I use it with a header redirect it will not show redir.php at all just redirect instantly. Let us see then...

Also, thank you for the input

EDIT: seems to work!

Comment: Or leave the htaccess as it is and just use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in the redir.php file.. like most frameworks do.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That did not work for some reason. Still not sure why.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Are you talking about using the `[NC,L]` flag instead of `[R,L]`? I have included an example for that too.

Comment: @AndreiS. Because for that you have to use `NC` flag. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes! I was suspecting something like this but thank you for clearing it up! Thank you! I've learned stuff today!