# Select value from mysql equal to URL

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to perform a MySQL query to select a record which contains the value of a part of an URL?

Per example the following page: http://example.com/select-this-one
In mysql I stored a value which contains the part of the URL. In this case "select-this-one".

How can I return the record from mysql which contains "select-this-one" only at the page http://example.com/select-this-one?

I tried following code, but doesn't work:

```
$uri = explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)); //PARSE THE URL
$value = $uri[1]; //SELECT FIRST SEGMENT OF THE URL

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = '0' AND record = '".$value."' ORDER BY ID DESC";
```

Comment: Doesn't work how?

Comment: Are you sure that `$value` contains what you think it should contain?

Comment: Do some debugging basics: what does `print_r($uri)` tell you? Or `echo $value`? Is it exactly the same as in your db ?

Comment: echo $value returns: select-this-one.php.
It also returns the part of the URL, but not in the query

Answer (score 0):

Your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` gets overwritten by a rewrite rule have a look here:
[Apache rewrite - get original URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493075/apache-rewrite-get-original-url-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

If your server has mod_rewrite enabled just add a
‘.htaccess’ file with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

Then the code you have should work.
(Assuming it is in the index.php file)