# How to echo real url without htacces rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have some url's that are rewritten by the htacces file. I want to echo the real urls.

Is this possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache rewrite - get original URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493075/apache-rewrite-get-original-url-in-php)

Comment: To get an answer its important to detail out the context of your problem, everything from the technology used to the host system, to what you have tried. Currently, you question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

If you are removing the extension of the file with .htaccess file you should probobly take the real url

```
$fullURL = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

And then use the str_replace function to replace the file extension

```
str_replace(".php","",$fullURL);
```